# mod_rewrite to redirect 301 all urls inside a folder after a domain change

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect 301 all pages of this domain inside folder1

http://domain.com/folder1/xxxxx/page1

with /xxxxx/ is any folder

to

https://newdomain.com/folder2/page1

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Sure we can help with fixing your code, but only if you post the code you have so far.

Comment: Please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. We are here to help with _specific issues_ you encounter _in your own code_. So start out yourself, if you run into serious issues, _then_ is the time to come here, post your code and point out that issue you ran into.

Comment: Sure. I wrote this code so far but is not working. I can't rid off the /xxxxx/ folder

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/folder2/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

Comment: Please do not add additional details in comments, that is very hard to read. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some small modifucations to your code, that should get you on the way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^/?folder1/[^/]+/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/folder2/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Glad I could help! Please do not forget to upvote and accept this answer ;-) Have fun!